# React MUI timeline dot color change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I want to override the default color of MUI TimelineDot component. I simply did this

```
<TimelineDot
sx={{
'& .MuiTimelineDot-root': { backgroundColor: '#00FF00' },
}}
/>
```

But this seems not working. What went wrong in my code?

This is my [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-violet-mnr6wi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to specify a class name or anything like that. Simply just change the color. Per the API [docs](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)

```js
<TimelineDot
  sx={{ 
    backgroundColor: '#00FF00'
  }}
/>
```

Comment: : ) Absolutely!